# How to filter out a custom JSDoc tag from on hover in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hover, jsdoc

I am currently engaged in writing a vscode extension that necessitates parsing of custom JSDoc tags. The tags are in JSON format and will have embedded text that can be verbose. 
[See example of @aCustomtag in the example JSDoc here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d42uU.png) 
The problem is that the tag content will spam the vscode on hover and this is not helpful to the user.
[See spam on on hover here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1v9q.png)

The project is based on this [this client server example](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/lsp-sample)

Is there a way to intercept the hover to filter out the content of custom JSDoc tags?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by VS Code's built-in JS/TS supported and we're unlikely to add support for it since it's quite specific

You can implement this filtering yourself using a [TypeScript language service plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin). The specific method you'd want to override is `getCompletionEntryDetails`. You can filter out the `tags` you want to hide on the `ts.CompletionEntryDetails` return type